# Html.EditorFor with shortDateTostring

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to show only date in my HTML.editorFor not date and time. i have tried with two different ways but dosn't work.
her's my code with to different trial :

```
<%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.Dd.ToShortDateString())%>
        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Dd) %>
    <br />
        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Df) %>
    <br />
        <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.Df, Model.Df.ToShortDateString()) %>
        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Df) %>
```

Any one got i idea ho to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could decorate your view model property with the [`[DisplayFormat]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute.aspx) attribute:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
public DateTime Df { get; set; }
```

This allows you to specify the format you wish to use when displaying and editing the property in the view.

Answer (score 1):

Just decorate your ViewModel Property with `[DataType(DataType.Date)]`
Then in your view use `@Html.EditorFor(m = > m.YourProperty)`

***Update:***

I mean something like this:

```
public class YourModel{
   [DataType(DataType.Date)]
   public DateTime YourProperty{get;set;}
}
```

then just use the default EditorTemplate for it :

```
Html.EditorFor(model => model.YourProperty)
```

Comment: i'm using connection To dataBase and  in My DB the type is already Date